# MySQL Error Number 150 when creating Table with Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints

I am having an issue creating a new table in my `database`. I've seen that the error code it is returning is to do with `Foreign Key` constraints.

I checked to ensure that the `data type` of the `foreign key` in the new table matched the `data type` of the `primary key` in the other table. They are both `int(11)`.

However I am still getting an error. Am I missing something? This is my `SQL` script for creating the new table:

```
CREATE TABLE `regular_features` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day` VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `programme_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`programme_id`) REFERENCES directoryprogramme(id) 
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is the original table  containing the `primary key`:

```
CREATE TABLE `directoryprogramme` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `broadcast_time` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `days` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  `contributors` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `directorycompany_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `directorycontact_id` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `facebook_link` VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `twitter_link` VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wikipedia_link` VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `web` VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageextension` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'other',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1161 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The `Foreign Key` will be the `id` of `directoryprogramme`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the last line of your create statement:

```
ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

You mix `MYISAM` in ald table with `INNODB` in your new table.

That doesn't work.

Chnage the engine in your new table to `MYISAM` and it works.